# How can I make pointer of an array point at the begining of array every time I go in for loop?

Tags: c, function, for-loop, pointers

So in the main program I have initialized an array, and I pass a pointer of an array to a function.
And in that function I access the same for loop for a certain amount of time.
e.g. Let's say we have an array, and a function that needs to for a certain number has to find 0 (and change it into 1) in that array and return sum of those indexes where they are, but that function also changes that array.
So how can I make the pointer always in for loop start at the beginning of the array (array[0])??

```
int function(int *pointer){
 int count = 3, sum = 0;

//changes the array, now only few places (but greater than 3) have 0

 while(count != 0){
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(*(pointer + i) == 0){
       sum+=i;
       *(pointer + i) = 1;
    }
  }
 }
 return sum;
}

int main(void){
 int array[10] = {0};
 int sum = function(array);
 printf("%d", sum);
 return 0;
}
```

And yes, it's extremally important to do it with the function.
Edit: for anyone asking why for in a while loop, well my actual program is a bit more complicated than what I said here and it requires to go into a for loop until some requirements are met

I have tried to add another variable that keeps the memory address of the beginning of the array
like int temp = pointer, and then after for loop put pointer = temp, but fails if counter is 3 or more. Also I have tried to remember the index it found the zero and keep on going in for loop with that for(int i = index; i < 10; i++) (ofc put at the beginning index = 0), still fails to accurately found the 0

Comment: Save the original pointer in a separate variable, and use it inside the loop.

Comment: Also, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. Please use the array-index syntax instead.

Comment: As Garrigan mentioned, you never modify `count`, so your `while` loop will never end. _Assuming_ that at least 3 array elements are 0, you probably want to add `--count;` under your `if`. If you do _not_ have 3 elements that are 0, you probably want to guarantee that the loop ends (e.g.): `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { if (pointer[i] == 0) { sum += i; pointer[i] = 1; if (--count == 0) break; } }`

Comment: You never change `pointer` ! So it **do point** to the first element of the array **all the time**.  So that's not the problem! Please describe the exact problem you have. What happens? What did you expect to happen? Is the problem "just" the endless loop? It happens because you never change `count`

Comment: And what is the purpose of having the `for` loop inside a `while`? Makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bracket indexing as "Some programmer dude" mentioned which will not require changing the pointer. So instead of reassigning the pointer just use `p[i]`.

Also I am a bit confused as you never modify the pointer, so it is always pointing at the beginning of the array.

Also you have an infinite loop as `count=3` and is never modified. So `count!=0` is always true.

Comment: @GarrigaStafford fair point I have not modified the count, I was a bit tired that's why I haven't wrote it here. I forgot. Well, my first thought was it must have been modified because it worked for the first two times going into a for loop, but then in third it skipped and went to fourth, in the context of this hypothetical task my array with all zeros was never modified and so I didn't understand why it skipped